# What is `extractForNativeBuild` in Android Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, pytorch, libtorch

I'm reading PyTorch tutorial to use LibTorch for native Android development [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/android#linking-to-prebuilt-libtorch-library-from-gradle-dependency) and see this:

```
android {
...
    configurations {
       extractForNativeBuild
    }
...
}

dependencies {
    extractForNativeBuild('org.pytorch:pytorch_android:1.10.0')
}
```

I cannot find any information about this `extractForNativeBuild` function, what is this?